# Convert Inline background image URLs to data-background

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, preg-replace

Im trying to change inline background style images to data-background

This is an example output that im expecting to have

```
<div id="parent" style="background-image:url(http://www.example.com/example.jpg);"></div>
```

Converted to

```
<div id="parent" data-background="http://www.example.com/example.jpg"></div>
```

but instead of falling into parent div, sometimes data-background falls into divs that are one or two levels above the parent div

Example

```
   <div data-background="http://www.example.com/example.jpg" id="onediv">
   <div id="anotherdiv">
   <div id="parent"></div>
   </div>
   </div>
```

All the above div ids are made for just an example

The following is the PHP Code which im trying my best if there any alternative please suggest me Thanks

```
   function add_background_placeholders( $content ) {
    // Don't lazyload for feeds, previews, mobile
    if( is_feed() || is_preview() )
        return $content;
    // Don't lazy-load if the content has already been run through previously
    if ( false !== strpos( $content, 'data-background' ) )
        return $content;
    preg_match_all('~\bstyle=(\'|")(.*?)background(-image)?\s*:(.*?)\(\s*(\'|")?(?<image>.*?)\3?\s*\);?~i',$content,$matches);

    if( empty( $matches ) ) return $content;

    foreach( $matches[0] as $match ){
         preg_match('~\bbackground(-image)?\s*:(.*?)\(\s*(\'|")?(?<image>.*?)\3?\s*\);?~i',$match,$bg);              
         $bg_less_match = str_replace( $bg[0], '', $match );             
         $data_match = 'data-background="'.$bg['image'].'" '.$bg_less_match;
         $content = str_replace( array($match.';', $match), array( $data_match, $data_match), $content);
    }

  return $content;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use a dom php library, get the node, then get the background attribute. use regular expression to process the css to extract the url. then set the data-background attribute, then export the entire dom document out.

eg.http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php

theres a few dom php libraries out there